# Excel VBA Code stops running after Workbook Open

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following problem: After I start opening a workbook that I have just created, the code stops running with no error. Have anyone a solution how the rest of the code can be excuted?

Thanks in Advance!

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

On Error GoTo Eingabefehler

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

ActiveSheet.Select
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

ThisWorkbook.Save

Dim strPath As String
Dim strName As String

UserForm1.Show

strPath = "C:\Users\Desktop\"
strName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=strPath & ".xlsx", FileFilter:="XLSX-File (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook

Dim WbDatei1 As Workbook
Dim WbDatei3 As Workbook

Set WbDatei1 = ThisWorkbook
Set WbDatei3 = Workbooks.Open(strName) 'VBA Code stops working from here

For Each shp In WbDatei3.Sheets(1).Shapes
shp.Delete
Next
WbDatei3.Save

WbDatei1.Sheets(1).Select
Selection.Columns("F:F").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Range("G2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IFERROR(TIME(HOUR(RC[-2]-RC[-5]),MINUTE(RC[-2]-RC[-5]),SECOND(RC[-2]-RC[-5])),"""")"
```

[...]

Comment: I have no XML file created, its just a code running in a xmls-file

Comment: Sorry, I was not so attentive. It looks that your file is saved as .xlsx workbook (`xlOpenXMLWorkbook`) and it is already open when you try opening it... And a .xlsx workbook does not have macros inside. If you use `SaveCopyAs` you maybe will be able to use the code as you try.

Comment: Thank you, I will try